# O certo é perguntar "Tudo bem?" ou "Tudo bom?"

Tags: expressões

Vejo diversas pessoas que ao perguntar pela outra questiona "Tudo bem?" e "Tudo bom?", o que me gera desconforto visto que sempre utilizo "Tudo bem?".

A minha dúvida é se ambas estão corretas, ou se o certo é perguntar apenas "Tudo bem?"?

Comment: Ambas as formas estão corretas, mas bem é um advérbio e bom é um adjetivo; de resto, acho que não há diferença

Comment: As respostas fizeram um ótimo trabalho a descortinar esta questão, mas queria só salvaguardar uma coisa: a língua é *construída* pelas pessoas que a usam, pelo que, se a expressão "tudo bom" é amplamente utilizada, então é correto perguntar "tudo bom" a alguém.

Claro que isto é discutível, mas parece-me que ser popular é condição necessária e suficiente para considerarmos que uma expressão existe e pode ser usada - pelo menos, num contexto coloquial, em que não temos de seguir regras tão "rígidas".

Answer (score 13):

***Tudo bem?*** e ***Tudo bom?*** são duas maneiras corretas diferentes de perguntar *a mesma* coisa. Ou melhor, mais do que perguntar, o que o locutor faz com *tudo bem/bom, Joana?* é manifestar interesse pelo bem-estar e felicidade da Joana. Do ponto de vista do uso prático, não creio que qualquer falante se consiga aperceber de qualquer diferença de significado entre as duas fórmulas. Eu pelo menos não consigo.

Agora, nós podemos esmiuçar gramaticalmente as duas expressões, mas vamos chega à mesma conclusão, tal como se chegou [aqui no *Duvidas de Português* (Dicio.com)](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/tudo-bem-ou-tudo-bom/). As expressões podem ser entendidas como reduções de ***está tudo bem*** e ***está tudo bom***.

**Está tudo bom, Joana?** Aqui o *tudo* designa tudo o que é importante para a Joana, e *bom* adjetiva *tudo*. Seria o mesmo que perguntar:

> Joana, a tua saúde está boa, a saúde dos teus está boa, as tuas relações com a família estão boas, a situação no trabalho está boa, a tu conta bancária está boa? Está tudo bom?

**Está tudo bem, Joana?** Aqui *tudo* tem o mesmo significado que acima, e *bem* adverbia o verbo *estar*. E o que significa uma coisa estar bem? Aqui o que nos interessa é o ponto de vista da Joana, e uma coisa estar bem do ponto de vista dela significa que a coisa está como a Joana gostaria, dentro do razoável, que ela estivesse. E naturalmente a Joana gostaria que a coisa estivesse boa, do seu ponto de vista. Portanto, do ponto de vista da Joana, *estar tudo bem* significa *estar tudo bom*, e vice-versa.

Agora, isto é uma justificação gramatical das expressões, não é uma explicação das suas origens. Eu tenho ideia, mas não consigo comprovar, que a expressão mais antiga, e em Portugal a mais comum, é *tudo bem*. Aliás *tudo bem* pode resultar da redução de *está tudo bem* e também de *vai tudo bem* ou *corre tudo bem*. Já *vai tudo bom* nunca ouvi, e *corre tudo bom* nem me parece que faça sentido.

Comment: Geralmente ao cumprimentar alguém de forma corriqueira a conversa fica entre um A: "Tudo bem?", e o B: "Tudo bom?", a resposta fica entre uma afirmação e pergunta ao mesmo tempo, então A dá alguma afirmação visual. Reparei que algumas pessoas fazem isso aqui em São Paulo. Talvez seja por essa "falta de tempo" que ocorrem diálogos sintetizados.

Comment: E depois de estar me familiarizado com o Português, pode apenas perguntar:
- Tudo?
Já é o suficiente para saber que está perguntando: Tudo bom / bem?

Comment: julgo que há todavia uma variação em função da variante da língua. Parece-me que no Brasil usa-se mais `tudo bom?` e em Portugal `tudo bem?`

Comment: @João, também me parece. Pelo menos, em Portugal, "tudo bem?" é claramente mais comum que "tudo bom?"

Comment: Na minha região usa-se os dois.  Eu mesmo uso ora um, ora outro.

Answer (score 9):

As duas maneiras são aceitas mas vale ressaltar que :

Se queremos enfatizar a maneira em que o ouvinte se encontra devemos usar ***bem***, que é um advérbio de modo.

Caso queira voltar a atenção para o seu estado no momento da pergunta devemos usar ***bom***, que é um adjetivo.

Logo as duas estão corretas só precisamos prestar atenção que a função de *bem* difere da função de *bom*.

Comment: Desconheço dessa diferença, e aliás, muita gente pergunta de ambas as formas mas sempre querem dizer a mesma coisa: "está tudo bem com a sua vida neste estado/época atual?"

Comment: o sentido pode variar entre pessoas, mas bem e bom são coisas diferentes mesmo (:

Comment: E então qual é a diferença entre "a maneira em que se encontra" e "o seu estado no momento"?

Answer (score 3):

*Bem* é um advérbio de modo.

*Bom* é um adjectivo.

Servem funções diferentes.

Perguntaria "está tudo bem" a uma pessoa, para saber como ela se sente em determinado momento ou como lhe corre a vida (se a vida vai bem ou se vai mal ― e nunca se vai bom ou se vai mau).

Perguntaria "está tudo bom" se, por exemplo, tivesse servido determinada refeição e quisesse saber se esta estava ao gosto da pessoa:

> ―Está tudo bom?
>   ―Sim, grato, o arroz de bacalhau está muito bem confeccionado. ― Ou seja, está muito bom.

Aliás, neste último exemplo, *bem* adverbia o modo do verbo *confeccionado* conjunto que indica que a condição é positiva, condição que pode ser sintetizada pelo adjectivo bom. Mas um não pode substituir o outro. Está muito "bom confeccionado" não faz sentido. E dizer que o arroz está muito bem é estranho a menos que se fale do estado de saúde da planta e não do seu sabor e textura.

Assim, se estamos a cumprimentar alguém, apenas "está tudo bem" faz sentido.

O facto de muita gente fazer de determinada maneira não faz com que isso seja correcto. Se bem que, por vezes, algumas expressões sejam, pelo uso, legitimadas. Porém, neste caso isso não faz sentido porque são coisas mesmos diferentes.

Um bocado o mesmo que me leva a não escrever de acordo com o acordo ortográfico e a utilizar a grafia que anteriormente utilizava cá em Portugal.

Comment: Se eu te encontrar e te perguntar “Tudo bom?” por que carga d’agua has de tu pensar que eu me refiro ao arroz de pato, ou ao que quer que estejas a comer na altura, em vez de á tua saude, á saude da tua familia, á tua situação no trabalho, emfim, a tudo quanto é importante para ti. É assim tão disparatado perguntar se a tua saude está boa, se a situação em casa está boa, se está tudo bom? Naturalmente que, dos multiplos modelos orthographicos que já se usaram para escrever em portuguez, cada um é livre de seguir o que quiser, mas não comprehendo que tem isso que ver com o resto da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

*Bom* é antônimo de ***mau*** e *bem* é antônimo de ***mal***.

MAU = ruim, pessoa com intenções de prejudicar algo ou alguém...

MAL = infelicidade, problemas de saúde, relacionado ao estado da pessoa...

Então, data à vênia, no meu ver, o correto é perguntar "Tudo bem?", uma vez que quase sempre queremos saber o estado da pessoa, se a pessoa está **bem**, não se a pessoa está **boa**. Acho que *bom* está relacionado às coisas que estão no entorno daquela pessoa e não ao estado dela propriamente dito. Horrível quando eu pergunto "Está tudo bem?" e o "fi" de Deus responde "Está tudo Bom".

Answer (score 1):

Acho que as respostas acima podem confundir um estrangeiro. Apesar de "bem" e "bom" terem, isoladamente, sentidos bem diferentes (um advérbio e um substantivo, como já explicaram acima), o fato é que as duas expressões "tudo bem?" e "tudo bom?" são igualmente usadas, tanto na pergunta quanto na resposta, e até onde percebo nenhum falante faz qualquer diferença entre elas. Eu nem saberia dizer qual é mais usada: uso e ouço ambas todos os dias.

Comment: um advérbio e um substantivo ?